# How do I set a default value for a UUID primary key column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, default, uuid

I'm using PostgreSQL.  I'm trying to create a primary key column taht is a UUID, so I ran this statement

```
ALTER TABLE my_object_times ADD PRIMARY KEY (id) DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

but I get the error

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
```

What is the proper way to write the above statement (I'm doing alter because I'm changing an existing primary key column)?

Comment: Duplicated in dba.StackExchange.com: [Default value for UUID column in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/122623/19079)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the column `id` already exists in the table and you want to modify it by making it the primary key and adding a default value, you can do it in 2 steps:

```
ALTER TABLE my_object_times ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE my_object_times ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

If the column doesn't exist at all, then you can create it with all the attributes you want, by simply doing:

```
ALTER TABLE my_object_times ADD id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

(I cannot test this right now but it should work)

Comment: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 15):

In order to use `uuid_generate_v4()`, you first need to execute:

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`

Comment: SQL Error [58P01]: ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory