# Restoring Postgres Database from backup does not work - public.uuid_generate_v1() does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore, postgresql-14

I am restoring a postgres database via .backup file from one postgres-14 instance to another:

`pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d mydatabase -v "mybackupfile.backup"`

The backup fails, complaining about

`pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  function public.uuid_generate_v1() does not exist`

However, the extension `uuid-ossp` that contains the respective function is installed on the target system.

What can I do about that?

---

The statment causing the error:

```
pg_restore: creating TABLE "data.mytable"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 215; 1259 155973 TABLE mytable superuser
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  function public.uuid_generate_v1() does not exist
LINE 53:     uuid uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v1(),
                               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Command was: CREATE TABLE data.mytable (
    my_id integer DEFAULT nextval('data.my_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    [...]
    uuid uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v1()
);
```

Comment: Maybe the extension wasn't installed into the `public` schema.

Comment: How can I prove that? I simply installed it by `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"`

Comment: You can check that using: `select extnamespace::regnamespace from pg_extension where extname = 'uuid-ossp'`

Comment: The result is `public`

Comment: What is the SQL statement that led to this error? Are you restoring into the same database where you created the extension?

Comment: yes, I am restoring into the same database. I add the statement in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extension;

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

A similar answer here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378089/how-do-i-set-a-default-value-for-a-uuid-primary-key-column-in-postgres/61061421#61061421)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, but I am not sure which part of it was responsible:

In psql, connecting to `mydbatabase` and then calling the statement

`SET search_path TO data, public;`

calling the  extension statement again:

`create statement if not exists "uuid-ossp"`

After that, the restore statement has been called successfully.